Command for installing macOS updates without entering password afterwards?
I looked at the softwareupdate command, but even after entering my password for sudo on sudo softwareupdate -aiR, softwareupdate itself asks for my password, so I have to enter it twice. I would like to automatically install updates on my Mac at schedule times, perhaps with launchd and a command.
